# Neural Network - updating weight matrix - back-propagation algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'm implementing neural network with the help of Prof Andrew Ng lectures or
[this](http://calypso.inesc-id.pt/docs/NN1.pdf), using figure 31 Algorithm.

I think I understood forward propagation and backward propagation fine, but confuse with updating weight (theta) after each iteration.

Q1. When and HOW to update weight (theta) matrix - theta1, theta2?

Q2. What is big Delta for? [Solved, thanks @xhudik]

Q3. do we have to add +1 (bias unit in input and hidden layer?)

Comment: The meaning of capital delta is explained directly below the pseudocode: It's an accumulator for the weight updates; The forward propagation is done for all training samples with the same (old) weight matrix. Then the weight matrix is updated. I think this is called batch learning.

Comment: @nikie could you please elaborate, how to weight matrix is updated? I couldn't find anything in that or may be I'm missing something

Comment: If you're using gradient descent, you'll just add the gradients times some learning rate to the weights.

Comment: I'm using back-prapogation algo, so is it like - w (weight matrix for l layer) = w + learning_rate *  delta(of that layer) * x (input vector)? I'm really confused with that ... may be its stupid question but still!

Comment: @codemuncher i'm not very good at neural networks, but AFAIK your equation is right, however, the best way how tto prove it is to implement some algorithm and compare results with some already working NN (e.g. some task in course Machine Learning at coursera.org taught by Andrew Ng) - good luck!

Comment: (Disclaimer: I'm the author) Just to help out the googlers who ended up here, I've implemented a matrix version in Python here: https://github.com/jorgenkg/python-neural-network

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q1: is explained by @nikie (Kudos)

Q2: Andrew NG presentations are great. However, you are pointing to one which is high-level and want to understand details. What about this: http://galaxy.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html It gives you much more details with useful graphics

Comment: hey @xhudik, this is great, but I'm still not done with Q1! I really don't understand update rule ...

Comment: the wights are updated during passing through the data. Each pass updates weights. How - it is explained in the article. Unfortunately, it is not self-explanatory and it takes time to fully understand ...